# Download screenshots (or other build artefacts) out of AppCenter

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I'm running Detox through appcenter-pre-build.sh where I generate screenshots of my app. Where should I write those screenshots, and how can I download them from AppCenter? Ditto for if I generate a HTML report, I'd like to download that artefact too